# Printing contents of a vector using auto variable

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I read in a book that a shorter way to iterate through a vector is as follows:

```
for (auto x : v) 
{
  cout << x << "\n";
}
```

When I tried the same out in my compiler I got two error messages stating:

> 'auto' changes meaning in C++11, please remove it range based 'for' loops only available in c++11" and " 'x' maybe used uninitialized in this function

Can someone please point out the error and the solution?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using CodeLite v10.0.0

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty CodeLite is not a compiler.

Comment: @SayangdiptoChakraborty That's an editor, not a compiler, which compiler are you using?

Comment: Thank you everyone, I didn't have C++11 enabled in CodeLite. It's working now.

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is correct. Be mindful that you're taking a copy of every element in `x` though, you might want to use `const auto&` instead.

You need to enable C++11 in your compiler - if you're using gcc or clang, you can simply pass the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't have the C++11 and 14 enabled in my IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are compiling your code with a C++11 compiler?

With `gcc` you need the `-std=c++11` flag:

```
g++ -std=c++11
```

Same for `clang`:

```
clang++ -std=c++11
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I didn't have the C++11 and 14 enabled in my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you use language features that were introduced in the C++11 standard, while compiling with a compiler (in a mode) that doesn't support C++11.

Solution is to use a compiler (in a mode) that does supports C+++11. If your compiler supports C++11 (and it probably does, since it knows of the change of meaning of `auto`), then its documentation will specify how to enable C++11 or later standard mode.

---

> What compiler are you using?
>
> gcc (tdm 64-1) 5.1.0

The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) of your compiler says:

> To select this standard in GCC, use the option -std=c++11; to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify -pedantic